# Double quote is not removing from excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have written a formula to create dynamic range in vlookup but double quotes are not being removed and #Value error is coming as result.

```
=VLOOKUP($I$2,"Materials!A"&MATCH($I$2,Materials!A:A,0)&":B5",2,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using indirect.

```
=VLOOKUP($I$2, indirect("Materials!A"&MATCH($I$2,Materials!A:A,0)&":B5"), 2, 0)
```